# If statement in a form PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, if-statement

I'm working on a code which has a form. The answer on the form needs to decide to which page it should go, but it doesn't work.

````
<html>  
<body>



<form action= "<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">
Temperatuur: <input type="text" name="graden"><br>
<input type="Submit">

           <?php
    if($_GET["graden"]>=28){
        $action = "Koelbox.php";
    }
    else{
        $action = "scrabble.php";
    };
    ?> 
</form>



</body>
</html> ```
````

Comment: "_but it doesn't work_" What exactly doesn't work? Have you made sure that `$_GET["graden"]` is actually set? (your form uses POST)

Comment: If you want to submit to a different script depending on what you've entered, you need to do that on the client in JavaScript.

Comment: You are defining $action after using it. Declare it before

Comment: Move semicolon  };  at the end of if statement

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare and initialize the variable before using it.

```
<?php
  if($_GET["graden"]>=28)
  {
    $action = "Koelbox.php";
  }
  else
  {
    $action = "scrabble.php";
  }
?> 

<form action= "<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">
  Temperatuur: <input type="text" name="graden"><br>
  <input type="Submit">   
</form>
```

First check the `GET` parameter, then set your `$action` variable accordingly and then use it in your echo.

Comment: @Dlk Correct, it is wrong indeed. Not sure if it throws an error. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

I just initialized the variable before the form, but as far as I see the IF statement doesn't see the input in the form.

```
<?php
  if($_GET["graden"]>=28)
  {
    $action = "Koelbox.php";
  }
  else
  {
    $action = "scrabble.php";
  }
?> 

<form action= "<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">
  Temperatuur: <input type="text" name="graden"><br>
  <input type="Submit">   
</form>
```